# Passing values from native project to shared project Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, auth0

Im currently facing an issue with using a 3rd party authenticator for my xamarin forms app. The code to execute has to be done natively in the platform project. The issue im facing is how to get the information(successful login, token, email etc) from the ios/android native project to the shared project for me to access it and continue the application. Below is an example of how the code looks below in the ios native project.

```
var client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                Domain = "example.us.auth0.com",
                ClientId = "123456789"
            });
            
            var loginResult =  await client.LoginAsync();
```

Comment: Auth0 has a sample that shows how to do this in Xamarin Forms (ignore the Azure bits and just look at the auth code) - https://auth0.com/blog/developing-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-functions/

Comment: @Jason thank you for article!

Comment: See [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)